# How to get a very large size response data in a soap object in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have an application in which I use Soap Web-Service in .net language. I have a structure like this :

**Problem :** The response is an array of tables. The size of the soap object is too large. When I access the web-service on web-browser, it shows all the data. But when I was trying to access it in android application, It is not able to get whole response. It breaks in half response...

```
<GetPickersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <GetPickersResult>
    <Picker>
      <Id>int</Id>
      <StartTime>dateTime</StartTime>
      <EndTime>dateTime</EndTime>
      <PickerCount>int</PickerCount>
    </Picker>
    <Picker>
      <Id>int</Id>
      <StartTime>dateTime</StartTime>
      <EndTime>dateTime</EndTime>
      <PickerCount>int</PickerCount>
    </Picker>
  </GetPickersResult>
</GetPickersResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the code by which I m able to get the data :

> HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
>   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
>
> ![> if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) {  SoapObject
>   soapObject =
>
> > (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;   Log.i("SoapObject soapObject",
> >     ""+soapObject); }]

Here is the response image:

[image]

Comment: Your response is not truncated. You are getting full response but logcat is not able to display the full response. You can check it by finding the length of the response array element. In your case try to log the number of picker element in response and compare the digit with web response.

Comment: I have 20 tables approx & the name of the 20th table is "TABLE_20". Before that I m nt getting any string by name "TABLE_20". I search "TABLE_20" in logcat & found it in response as I m nt able to see it in response.It means response contains the last table but not able to show, its fine. I got this response bu the line: SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;   and then convert it into json object by : JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(soapObject.getPropertyAsString(0));.Then why I am not able to get full data in jsonObject.When I search, then only one time existence it shows.

Comment: @Maddy i agree with ravi.logcat is not able to display the full response.Check for the length.

Comment: @Maddy What do you mean by one time existence?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj;
jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse()))

I think my jsonObject is not able to execute all the response string. Is there any issue with json object length.

Comment: I believe that it executes very well. If it doesn't, try to debug your code more precisely, because it doesn't truncate or skip the response.

Comment: Ok, I'll try at my code side!

Answer (score -1):

try use like this;

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: That will crash with a very large response data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813407/android-ksoap2-received-data-exceeds-maxjsonlength-how-to-increase